# Querying Python Functions by Signature

Tags: python, reflection

What's the best way to document/decorate your Python functions/methods so that you're able to easily query them by signature (e.g. argument count, argument type, and return type)?

I'm playing around with a genetic-programming package, and I'd like to extend it to be able to dynamically replace a function in an expression by randomly selecting a replacement from all functions in my module with an equivalent signature.

I was thinking about rolling my own decorator, so I could do something like:

```
@validate(args=((int, range(1,10), (float, range(1,10)), (bool,)), returns=(int,range(-10,10))
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    result = do_stuff
    return result
```

and then be able to query similar functions by doing something like:

```
similar_functions = find_functions(like=myfunc)
```

Are there any standard tools or libraries along this line?

Comment: Do you know [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)?

Comment: +1, but you need Python 3 for them.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a solution for Python 2.6+

Comment: See if http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577065-type-checking-function-overloading-decorator/ or http://docs.python.org/library/inspect#inspect.getargspec helps. If you add type (and size) information to arg names, it should work with inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get function's argument list using `inspect`. This includes default values, but of course cannot provide types, because the very definitions lack this info.

Decorators like the one you shown seem the best solution for 2.x if you need type info. But I'd probably make their syntax a bit less parenthesized:

```
@validate(a=(int, 1, 10), b=(float, 1, 10), c=bool, returns=(int, -10, 10))
def foo(a, b, c): ...
```

You may detect obvious errors if your decorator will actually inspect function's arglist and make sure that it matches decorator's arguments. It need not modify the actual function if you don't aim to add validation code.

Note that you'll need special handling for `*arg` and `**kwarg`: those are far harder to provide type info for, and I don't know how much `f1(int, int, int)` is similar to `f2(int, *ints)`, let alone `f3(int, **kwargs)`.

Comment: I ended up tweaking the typecheck package, and this is pretty close to what I did.

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with the "we're all adults here" mentality, why need you ensure that the specified types are actually adhered to? *You* know what the signature of the function is meant to be, so just tag each function with a decorator and store the tags in a dictionary.

```
>>> import collections
>>> tags = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>>
>>> def tag(tag):
...     def decorator(func):
...             tags[tag].add(func)
...             func.tag = tag
...             return func
...     return decorator
...
>>> @tag("foo")
... def a(): pass
...
>>> @tag("foo")
... def b(): pass
...
>>> tags['foo']
{<function b at 0x0000000002BF2448>, <function a at 0x0000000002BD5A48>}
```

---

`similar` is trivial:

```
def similar(func):
    return signatures[func.sig]
```

Comment: I'm using a genetic algorithm, so what *I* know is not as important as what the *algorithm* knows. It simplifies my job immensely to have the types explicitly documented, so the algorithm knows not to waste its time comparing functions that may have the same number of arguments, but have vastly different types.

Comment: @Chris: but surely you write the functions yourself? Just document the types at runtime by some arbitrary but well-defined mapping of signature <-> tag, and your algorithm can choose whichever signature you want. You could even enforce your own standards, maybe by using Haskell type notation or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> dynamically replace a function in an expression by randomly selecting a replacement from all functions in my module with an equivalent signature.

Just do this.

```
all_functions_of_some_sig = [
    myfunc, myfunc2, myotherfunc, ... 
]
```

It's not that hard.  And it's more likely to work because any filtering or matching will be done by the designer of the function.

---

This is probably simpler

```
def myfunc( a, b, c ):
    return something
myfunc.args= ((int, range(1,10), (float, range(1,10)), (bool,))
myfunc.returns= (int,range(-10,10))

patterns= collections.defaultdict( list )
for f in __all__:
    patterns[f.args,f.returns]= f
```

Is that what you want?

All you have to do then is make sure that `__all__` lists all the relevant functions.  Not hard to do, and often expected of a module which includes *thousands* of functions.

Comment: This is terribly impractical. I have thousands of functions, that may well span hundreds of unique signatures. I have to manually document the types, but this would mean I'll also have to manually group them, which would be a nightmare.

Comment: @Chris S: You wrote them.  You're documenting them.  How does grouping them transcend into "nightmare"?